# How to get row numbers without duplicating

Tags: sql

I want to get row numbers from list. I tried `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK` with different variations, getting just duplicated rows.

With my code (code is below) SQL returns list of all orders, which are including some product id's of order 20 (those three products `'1013', '1024', '1025'`).

Problem is when I try to get `row_numbers` out of that list, it duplicate some rows because there are more than one product including in that order.

With my code it look like this:

```
Order_number
20
22
27
```

With `ROW_NUMBER()` it looks like this and that is problem:

```
Row_number | Order_number
1            20
2            20
3            20
4            22
5            27
6            27
```

I want it look like this:

```
Row_number | Order_number
1            20
2            22
3            27
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_ID AS 'ORDERS, WHICH HAVE AT LEAST ONE PRODUCT OF ORDER 20'

FROM ORDERS

INNER JOIN STORAGE ON ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID = STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID

WHERE STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID IN ('1013', '1024', '1025');
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `exists`, so you don't have to deal with duplicate elimination:

```
SELECT o.ORDER_ID
FROM ORDERS o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STORAGE S
              WHERE o.PRODUCT_ID = s.PRODUCT_ID AND
                    s.PRODUCT_ID IN (1013, 1024, 1025)
             );
```

With an index on `STORAGE(ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)` this should have very good performance.

You can also do this directly using aggregation on `STORAGE`:

```
SELECT s.ORDER_ID
FROM STORAGE S
WHERE s.PRODUCT_ID IN (1013, 1024, 1025)
GROUP BY s.ORDER_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, first one is very interesting. But there is not order id in storage, only product id.

I got it work with this compination:

`SELECT distinct DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_ID ASC) ROW, ORDER_ID
FROM ORDERS O
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STORAGE S
              WHERE O.PRODUCT_ID= S.PRODUCT_ID AND
                    S.PRODUCT_ID IN (1013, 1024, 1025)
             );`

Answer (score 1):

1.Get your distinct `ORDER_ID` first, then number:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_ID), ORDER_ID
FROM
  (
    SELECT ORDER_ID
    FROM ORDERS    
    INNER JOIN STORAGE ON ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID = STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID    
    WHERE STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID IN ('1013', '1024', '1025')
    GROUP BY ORDER_ID
  ) dt
```

2.Don't join to `STORAGE` table, instead use a correlated subquery

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID), ORDER_ID
 FROM ORDERS o
 WHERE EXISTS 
     (
         SELECT 1
         FROM STORAGE s
         WHERE s.PRODUCT_ID IN ('1013', '1024', '1025')
           AND s.PRODUCT_ID = o.PRODUCT_ID
     ) dt
```

3.Use DENSE_RANK() (haven't tested since you don't say what RDBMS you are using, but it may work)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_ID), ORDER_ID
    FROM ORDERS    
    INNER JOIN STORAGE ON ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID = STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID    
    WHERE STORAGE.PRODUCT_ID IN ('1013', '1024', '1025')
```

Comment: 2. makes the most sense - at least to me.

Comment: Third one was working. With first and second sql sayd ```incorrect syntax near ')'.``` Tried solve it, but no results.

Comment: @masteroscar I fixed up the first and second. I was just missing an alias for the derived tables/subquery.

Comment: @JNevil, I'll try them. This derived tables are completely new thing for me. Thanks.